# Is there a different baking process for whole wheat or other grain matzot?

Tags: matzah, dagan-five-grains

Inspired by [this question](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/90934/5275), I am curious if whole wheat matzot involve a different baking process than white flour matzot?

Most of the matza production uses white flour. I have read and heard that the matzot must be baked within 18 minutes after water is added to the flour. Is this 18-minute limit increased or reduced when using whole wheat flour?

What about barley or spelt? I gather that oats don't rise, but, perhaps, they are abiding by the 18-minute rule, anyway, as a standard for all matzot?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this 18-minute limit increased or reduced when using whole wheat flour?

From [ok.org](http://www.ok.org/consumers/passover/this-matzah-that-we-eat/)

> **Regardless of the type of flour used** or whether made by hand or machine, it is critical to ensure that the matzah dough does not become chometz during the baking process itself. Chazal tell us that under normal conditions it takes **at least eighteen minutes for dough to become chometz**. This time can change dramatically, however, with changes in the surrounding environment. On the one hand, heat will significantly hasten the process, and for this reason the oven in a matzah bakery is segregated from the area where the dough is handled. On the other hand, as long as the dough is being kneaded, it will never become chometz.

So in order for it not to become chometz, they will either do it in 18 min. or, keep kneading instead.

Comment: +1 for the answer. I'm not absolutely sure, but, I'm assuming that when chaza"l said "dough", it's possible that they meant only wheat dough, as that was the "standard" grain used. It's still possible that given the same environment, non-wheat dough may take longer than 18 minutes. I guess someone would have to do an experiment, or I may have to find a *matz*-giach :-)

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge, all industrial hand-made matzot follow the 18 minute rule (and machine matzot follow the 18 minute rule per batch). This is the same, independent from the type of flour (wheat, spelt, or oat).

Also, to my knowledge, no one bakes matzot using barley.

Comment: I'm also unaware of barley matzot. But someone told me that a few years ago, he saw multi-grain matzot (wheat, oats and rye, I think.)

Comment: @DanF I saw wheat and rye machine matzot this year (marketed as rye on the label).